# How can I have a certain Input (A normal Text input or Dropdown) Show up on a certain button click?

Tags: html

I'm currently building out the front-end forms for a website I'm helping build out, and I'm trying to figure out how to have either a text input or a dropdown show up depending on what button the user selects. Is there a way I can do this? For example maybe through JavaScript, Jquery and the like? I'd appreciate the help :)

Here's the code I'm taking this off of. I'm sorry if the answer is simple to some, I'm just not sure how to really go about it.

(disclaimer) My goal is to have the dollar amount as a text input, and the percentage as the dropdown here. (also thank you Dan for formatting this, already helped me clean most of the site code <3)

```
<label>
  <strong>Express Down Payment as a dollar amount or percentage ("Loan Amount")</strong>
</label>
<button id="dollar">Dollar Amount</button>
<button id="percentage">Percentage</button>
<br/>
<label>
  <strong>Are you working with a lender company?</strong>
</label>
<select name="lender" style="width:705px;height:40px">
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<br/>
```

Comment: Which button is supposed to show which element(s)?

Comment: The dollar Amount, I'm trying to have a dropdown for that, each option increasing, say by 2,000 each, and the percentage as a text input, but having the dollar amount as a text input and a Percentage as the dropdown from 1% to around 10% would be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
[view] .div {display:none;}
[view="boy"] .boy {display:block;}
[view="girl"] .girl {display:block;}
</style>

<div view='boy'>
      <input type='button' value='Boy' onclick="this.parentElement.setAttribute('view','boy')">
      <input type='button' value='Girl' onclick="this.parentElement.setAttribute('view','girl')">
       <div class='div boy'>
            <select>
                  <option>Game</option>
                  <option>Drink</option>
             </select>
       </div>
       <div class='div girl'>
            <select>
                  <option>Dress</option>
                  <option>Club</option>
             </select>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's either `Amount` or `Percentage` then two buttons is not a good design choice, another control such as a drop down is a better option.

```js
function showDownPaymentField(element) {
  document.getElementById('amount-field').style.display = element.value == 'amount' ? 'block' : 'none';
  document.getElementById('percent-field').style.display = element.value == 'percent' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

div.field-container {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

div.field-container label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-container">
  <label>
    <strong>Express Down Payment as a dollar amount or percentage ("Loan Amount")</strong>
  </label>
  <select id="downPaymentChoice" name="downPaymentChoice" onchange="showDownPaymentField(this)">
    <option value="">Please choose...</option>
    <option value="amount">Dollar Amount</option>
    <option value="percent">Percentage</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="amount-field" class="hidden">
  <label>Down payment amount</label><br/>
  <select name="downPaymentAmount" id="downPaymentAmount">
    <option value="1000">$ 1,000</option>
    <option value="2000">$ 2,000</option>
    <option value="3000">$ 3,000</option>
    <option value="4000">$ 4,000</option>
    <option value="5000">$ 5,000</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="percent-field" class="field-container hidden">
  <label>Down payment percentage</label><br/>
  <input name="downPaymentPercentage" id="downPaymentPercentage" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="field-container">
  <label>
    <strong>Are you working with a lender company?</strong>
  </label>
  <select name="lender" style="width:705px;height:40px">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm, the use of divs causes the input fields to not show altogether so there must be a compatibility issue in the code itself thats causing the issue, since one of my people in my work team built it out before me. I'm not sure if I'd be able to send you the html file either considering I'm under NDA (This is for a company site in the works)